# About reading user input within a function and outputting the result

Tags: c++

I've recently been assigned with the task to declare a function, and within that function, read user input 3 times, store that input into 3 variables, and return one value that is calculated by doing operations of sorts to those three variables.

As such, I have had no luck, and need advice.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double calcABCsum(int a, int b, int c);

int main()
{
    int a,
        b,
        c;

    double x;

    calcABCsum();

    cout << "The sum is: " << x;

    return 0;
}

double calcABCsum()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    double x;

    cout << "Please enter a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Please enter b: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Please enter your c: ";
    cin >> c;

    x = a + b + c;

    return x;
}
```

My code doesn't compile the way I want it to. Basically, I'm looking for a way to read user input in a function and output the result. Thanks!

Comment: Your x in the function is a local variable, meaning that it doesn't have any effect on the global variable x that you initialised outside the function. Also, you can do `int a, b, c;` instead of the current variable initialisation. If you want to make it even more efficient, you can code `return a+b+c;` instead of the current returning. This would also remove the need for `double x;`.

Comment: If you are referring to an actual compile error, you need to change your function header at the top to match your function definition. (It takes no parameters). If you're referring to the wrong value being output, then I think that question has already been answered.

Comment: Some general advice: "read user input 3 times, store that input into 3 variables, and return one value" this is generally bad design, because one function should not read input and compute a result at the same time, rather this should be split into separate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main problems.

1. You are declaring the function `calcABCSum()` at the top of your file as a function which takes 3 variables, but then when you define it below, it takes no parameters.
2. Once you fix the first issue, you are still just declaring a variable `x` and not assigning it to any value.

You need to assign your local `x` variable to the return value of the function you are calling:

```
double x = calcABCSum(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: That makes sense, actually.

Once I assigned x to my function, it said it had too little arguments in the function so I used a, b, and c. Now, the logs are saying it is returning 1 because there is an "undefined refrence". Currently trying to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: See my post below